# BadMethodCallException in Validator.php for custom rule added for laravel 5.2

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I have created `CustvalidationadminClass.php` inside my project folder  app/validators and defined a class `Custvalidationadmin`, and then added created the rule by calling that class and method from it here in `AppServiceProvider.php`  inside `boot()` method this line

```
Validator::extend('checkadminusername', 'CustvalidationadminClass@checkadminusername');
```

Then i used this rule from my controller for checking purpose located in `app/providers` . Now the problem is that it is showing this error `BadMethodCallException`. Previously it was working fine , but suddenly today it is not working and also i have tried to create a new custom rule that is also not working . I need help on this kindly show mw some way to get solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem has been solved by executing a command in terminal from my project folder . The following composer command i have used .

composer dumpautoload